# could not find '../HMS/server/models/user' in node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, github

hi i am working on one application where my application folder structure is like shown below**(please click on image link given below)**. and i want to use below line in passport.js file.

**var User = require('../server/models/user');**

but i get below error when i run tried few possible ways please look and suggest a solution.

```
abcd@abcd-PC MINGW64 /e/Node Projects/HMS
$ node server
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server\config\passport.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

abcd@abcd-PC MINGW64 /e/Node Projects/HMS
$ node server
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server\routes\routes.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server.js:41:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

abcd@abcd-PC MINGW64 /e/Node Projects/HMS
$ node server
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '.../models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server\config\passport.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

abcd@abcd-PC MINGW64 /e/Node Projects/HMS
$ node server
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server\routes\routes.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server.js:41:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

abcd@abcd-PC MINGW64 /e/Node Projects/HMS
$ node server
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module ' ../models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server\config\passport.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

abcd@abcd-PC MINGW64 /e/Node Projects/HMS
$ node server
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../server/models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server\config\passport.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

abcd@abcd-PC MINGW64 /e/Node Projects/HMS
$ node server
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../server/models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server\config\passport.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

abcd@abcd-PC MINGW64 /e/Node Projects/HMS
$ node server
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server\routes\routes.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server.js:41:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

abcd@abcd-PC MINGW64 /e/Node Projects/HMS
$ node server
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './server/models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server\config\passport.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

abcd@abcd-PC MINGW64 /e/Node Projects/HMS
$ node server
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'HMS/server/models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server\config\passport.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

abcd@abcd-PC MINGW64 /e/Node Projects/HMS
$ node server
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../HMS/server/models/user'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server\config\passport.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Node Projects\HMS\server.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

***[please find link to image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xi4M.png)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both `/config` and `/models` folders are in the `/server` folder, it should be:

```
var User = require('../models/user');
```